# How can I set the value of a variable equal to a string or to the string "0" depending on a function call?

Tags: javascript

I am using this to populate a field from local storage:

```
   var a = localstorage.get('sCreatedBy');
```

I notice that when there's **no** entry for the local storage then:

`localstorage.get('sCreatedBy')` returns the string `"null"`

How can I make it so that the above will populate the variable a with a value of `"0"` 
if there's the string `"null"` returned or with the real value if a value that's not
equal to the string `"null"` is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value = localstorage.get('sCreatedBy') ;
var a = (value != "null") ? value : 0;
```

Comment: @Anne Thanks for the correction, I got mixed up between two examples.